# Using javascript to check if m3u8 live stream is active

Tags: javascript, live-streaming, m3u8, tvml

### Issue

I have a TVML app which calls a m3u8 live stream. The problem is that if the stream isn’t active, the video player throws an error message which cannot be customized. What I want to do is to check if the stream is live before attempting to play it. Is there a way I can accomplish this in javascript?

### Error:

(update)

> the TVJS playbackError event returns an IKJSError with code -1008, description: resource unavailable and domain: NSUrlErrorDomain. This Error also has an underlyingError (also IKJSError) with code -12884, description: “The operation couldn't be completed. (CoreMediaErrorDomain error -12884 - Playlist File not received)”.

The problem is that when this error is received the player immediately shows an error message on the TV which I can't replace. This is why I want to check if stream is live before attempting to play it.

Comment: What is the error thrown?

Comment: Just updated the question with the error received from the playbackError event.

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
async function checkHLSActive(url) {
    try {
        let res = await axios.head(url);
        return /2\d\d/.test('' + res.status);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', url, err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to import axios library for wherever you put this.

Comment: well this didn't work for me, I'm getting cors from the URL requested.